# Unable to calculate working hours within a date range Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

if someone can help with issue below.

I have a table in which I have dates with time in one columns, in second column prijava_odjava I have 1 and 2 by which 1 means coming to work and 2 means leaving the work. I would like to calculate, how much hours the workers are logged in CRM per day. Clearly my code below works with wrong results because it takes min date for 1 and max date for 2 across the whole table and not by the desired date.

```
SELECT CAST(dnevnik_prijave.datum as date),ime_priimek, id_uporabnik,
    (SELECT min(datum) 
     from dnevnik_prijave 
     WHERE dnevnik_prijave.id_uporabnika=uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
     AND prijava_odjava='1' 
     AND datum>='2020-04-01' 
     AND datum<='2020-04-17'
     GROUP BY uporabniki.id_uporabnik) as prihod,        
    (SELECT max(datum) 
     FROM dnevnik_prijave 
     WHERE dnevnik_prijave.id_uporabnika=uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
     AND prijava_odjava='2' 
     AND datum>='2020-04-01' 
     AND datum<='2020-04-17') as odhod,      
    (SELECT extract(epoch from (odhod - prihod))/3600 as delovne_ure
     FROM (SELECT
                (SELECT min(datum) 
                 FROM dnevnik_prijave 
                 WHERE dnevnik_prijave.id_uporabnika=uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
                 AND prijava_odjava='1' 
                 AND datum>='2020-04-01' 
                 AND datum<='2020-04-17' 
                 GROUP BY uporabniki.id_uporabnik) as prihod,
                (SELECT max(datum) 
                 FROM dnevnik_prijave
                 WHERE dnevnik_prijave.id_uporabnika=uporabniki.id_uporabnik 
                 AND prijava_odjava='2' 
                 AND datum>='2020-04-01' 
                 AND datum<='2020-04-17') as odhod) as tabela1)
FROM uporabniki, dnevnik_prijave
WHERE dnevnik_prijave.id_uporabnika=uporabniki.id_uporabnik
AND dnevnik_prijave.datum >='2020-04-01' and dnevnik_prijave.datum<='2020-04-17'
GROUP BY (cast(dnevnik_prijave.datum as date)), uporabniki.id_uporabnik
ORDER BY (cast(dnevnik_prijave.datum as date)),ime_priimek asc
```

Example Table dnevnik_prijave (which I link with table uporabniki to get names) is below.

```
  id    username          datum               id_uporabnika prijava_odjava
  21424 worker 1    2020-04-17 11:47:06.119505      5000    1
  21422 worker 2    2020-04-17 10:52:24.291133      5001    1
  21426 worker 1    2020-04-17 13:53:57.757468      5000    2
  21425 worker 2    2020-04-17 13:35:40.584538      5001    2
  21424 worker 1    2020-04-17 14:01:06.119505      5000    1
  21422 worker 2    2020-04-17 15:52:24.291133      5001    1
  21426 worker 1    2020-04-17 17:53:57.757468      5000    2
  21425 worker 2    2020-04-17 17:35:40.584538      5001    2
  21424 worker 1    2020-04-18 11:47:06.119505      5000    1
  21422 worker 2    2020-04-18 10:52:24.291133      5001    1
  21426 worker 1    2020-04-18 13:53:57.757468      5000    2
  21425 worker 2    2020-04-18 13:35:40.584538      5001    2
  21424 worker 1    2020-04-18 14:01:06.119505      5000    1
  21422 worker 2    2020-04-18 15:52:24.291133      5001    1
  21426 worker 1    2020-04-18 17:53:57.757468      5000    2
  21425 worker 2    2020-04-18 17:35:40.584538      5001    2
```

Table I would like to get is following:

```
datum        ime_priime id_uporabnik    prihod           odhod           delovne
17.04.2020  LAZY WORKER 5000    2020-04-17 11:47:06 2020-04-17 17:53:57   6,2
17.04.2020  HARD WORKER 5001    2020-04-17 10:52:24 2020-04-17 17:35:40   6,6
18.04.2020  LAZY WORKER 5000    2020-04-18 11:47:06 2020-04-18 17:53:57   6,2
18.04.2020  HARD WORKER 5001    2020-04-18 10:52:24 2020-04-18 17:35:40   6,6
```

I hope itis more understandable now....

Comment: Will be better to post your tables structure and sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as you discovered is that the Min and Max functions return the values in absolute terms but have no concept intermediate values. Those you can the [Window Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) LEAD. This function extract columns from the next row(s). In this case we get the combine the datum values from the '1 row' with the following '2 row', resulting a single row for each in/out set. Since each is a timestamp those values can be subtracted to produce an [Interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) between them and later Summed to produce the total work hours per day.  
The query below accomplish that, with explanation comments at each step (from the inside out).

```
-- 5. finally since the window function used does not eliminate duplicate rows remove them now.
-- also convert the interval to a decimal number of hours to 1 decimal place. (ie .1hours)
select distinct on (wkday, id_uporabnika)
       to_char(wkday, 'yyyy-mm-dd') datum
     , username
     , id_uporabnika
     , datum     prihod
     , datum2    odhod
     , round( (extract('hours' from hrstotal)  + extract('minute' from hrstotal) /60)::numeric,1)
  from ( -- 4. now we have in hand an interval with actual time worked between for each '1 row' and corresponding '2 row'
         -- and intervals can cam be added, resulting in the actual hours for a single day  
         select wkday, username, id_uporabnika, datum, datum2
              , sum(wkhours) over( partition by id_uporabnika, wkday
                                       order by id_uporabnika, wkday
                                 ) hrstotal
           from ( -- 3, since datum from both rows (datum and datum2) are timestamps they can be subtracted directly
                  -- resulting in an interval. that interval being the time worked the between '2 row' and the '1 row'
                  -- and since the rows are now 'combined' discard the 2 row.  
                  select dp2.*, datum2-datum wkhours
                    from ( -- 2. pick up each '1 row' and combine the subsequent 2 row (lead function) by id_uporabnika and wkday
                           -- the result being the in time (datum from '1 row') and corresponding out time (datum from '2 row')
                           -- exist in the same row. 
                           select dp1.*
                                , lead(datum) over(partition by id_uporabnika, wkday 
                                                        order by id_uporabnika, datum
                                                  ) datum2 
                             from ( 
                                    -- 1. select the necessary columns and derive the date for reporting (wkday)                                
                                    select username, datum, id_uporabnika, prijava_odjava
                                         , date_trunc('day', datum) wkday
                                      from dnevnik_prijave
                                  ) dp1
                         ) dp2
                   where prijava_odjava =  1
                ) dp3
       ) db4 
 order by wkday, id_uporabnika ;
```

There are a couple items to look out for:

- If the timestamps for each id_uporabnika in the 1,2 .. 1,2 ... pattern the resulting interval will be null.
- The datum for the 1st '1 row' (prihod) and the datum for the last '2 row' (odhod) for each id_uporabnika is contained in the final result. However the total work time (delovne) cannot be derived from these values as they don't account for non-worked time between a '2 row' and the following '1 row'.
- I have no idea how you went from worker 1, worker 2 to Hard Worker, Lazy Worker. So I didn't even try.